# How do video games like Age of Empires code how a soldier spots an enemy soldier and decides to attack?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, computer-games

I was just curious how do RTS games actually implement this.
There are usually thousands of units on the whole map. They all have usually unique range of sight and then there's also settings for aggressiveness.
Secondly when an enemy unit goes out of range of sight the unit stops aggressing on the enemy unit. So how does a RTS game code this in an optimized way?

Comment: See also https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search